# How to return two values from one method

Tags: java, methods, return-value

I am trying to create a method that returns the fastest marathon time from an array (int times[]) of times, and also gives the corresponding name of the individual who ran that time.  The names of individuals are in a separate array (String names[]). The order of times[] corresponds to the order of names[], meaning the name of the person in names[0] has a running time of times[0], and so on.

I have been able to return the lowest integer from times[].  I am having trouble figuring out how to link the lowest time to the name of the runner, and print both values (e.g., names[0] + ": " + times[0]).  Any help would be appreciated.

*I would like to see how this is done **without** the use of a pair class.

Here is my code thus far.

```
public class Marathon {

static int i = 0;

public static Integer firstPlace(int[] value) {
    int time = value[0];
    while (i < value.length) {
        if (value[i] > time) {
            time = value[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return time;
}

public static void main (String[] arguments) {
    String[] names = {
            "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", "Matt", "Alex",
            "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane", "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda",
            "Aaron", "Kate"
    };
    int[] times = {
            341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299,
            343, 317, 265
    };

    System.out.println(Marathon.firstPlace(times));
}
}
```

Comment: return as array of Object

Comment: return new Pair<>("name", "time");

Comment: I voted to reopen because it's the XY problem. There is no need to return 2 values, and OP should realise why.